# Why Ethereum Wallet shows Xxx blocks left but doesn't catch up (for 2 hrs)?

Tags: wallets

Just started using the latest version of Ethereum Wallet from official website. This is the second day actually. Last night it sync-ed all night and seems to be ready for use. Today I started it, and later it discovered 200+ blocks to sync, and but now it stays at 196 left and 39%, and haven't moved since (for 2 hours).

Wondering if this is expected, and trying to understand what it could be doing to catch up?

Further more, about how Geth work maybe: how can it discover there are a number of blocks to be sync-ed before receiving them? I thought the process of blockchain is that clients receive block chains from peers and always keep the longest ones. Seems to me that means clients will know the content of the blocks when they receive them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointless to say that is a very unpleasant problem of many users. I had the same problem with the final 200 blocks in which it stops forever.
Try to change the internet time to "time.nist.gov".
Control panel--> Clock,Language...--> Date and time--> Internet time. Before that i run the wallet i run geth.
I' ve done it yesterday.
For me it worked (it finish all the block and finally i can see my balance), but after some times is stuck again on the last blocks (180) for much time. Now is slowly proceeding.

Comment: Followed your advice and set to "time.nist.gov". Let me see how it works out. I also switched to the lite client in the Develop menu of Mist / Ethereum Wallet 0.9.3 to see if it helps at all. I will come back and mark your answer if it turns out working. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently the combination of (1) setting time to "time.nist.gov", and (2) switching to lite client worked. Thanks @scorpion2185 for the first half.

Comment: I tried test mode once and then the wallet ran only in that mode. Now i'm stuck with the chaindate

Comment: I tried test mode once and then the wallet ran only in that mode even if i chose default mode. So i also switched to lite client, the only mode that worked. And setting time to "time.nist.gov" make me see for the first and only time my balance.Now i' m stuck with the chaindata every time the wallet starts again.

Comment: I meant the chain structure instead of chaindata.

Comment: i found this maybe can be of help, now i'm trying. https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1257

Comment: Now i select again light client that was removed and it has done the trick. Wallet fully synchronized!!! @Roy